# How to find the old version numbers for an Atmosphere (meteor) package?

Tags: meteor

The latest version of an `Atmosphere (meteor)` package has a serious bug, so I want to indicate an old version number for it. But I can't find a version list of it on its `Github` page nor on the Atmosphere page.

Is there a way to list up all version numbers of an `Atmosphere (meteor)` package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `meteor show` command, spcifically with the `--show-all` flag like this:

```
meteor show --show-all package:name
```